# Medsphere.Widget installation errors,(in ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, mono, widget, gtk#

My opreration:Ubuntu 12.04

```
  Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1

  GTK# 2.12.0.0
```

I downloaded "Medsphere.Widget",and when I did these steps fellowed by"INSTALL"

I met these troublesome:

> error CS1705: Assembly **gdk-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f** references `Mono.Cairo,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'
>   which has higher version number than imported assembly`Mono.Cairo,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'
>   ./PixbufCellRenderer.cs(74,52): error CS0121: The call is ambiguous
>   between the following methods or properties:
>   `System.Math.Ceiling(decimal)' and`System.Math.Ceiling(double)'
>   /usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to
>   previous error) ./PixbufCellRenderer.cs(75,53): error CS0121: The call
>   is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   `System.Math.Ceiling(decimal)' and`System.Math.Ceiling(double)'
>   /usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to
>   previous error) Compilation failed: 3 error(s), 0 warnings make: ***
>   [Medsphere.Widgets.dll] error 1

What should I do for the errors?

Comment: Medsphere.Widget( https://medsphere.org/community/project/medsphere-widgets)

Comment: hi，all,i find a  solution to the problem,see this page:https://medsphere.org/thread/1777?tstart=0